# Build with release configuration but automation tracetemplate launch app from simulator show target app not frontmost

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

Xcode version is 5.0.2 with latest iOS system.

I changed run's scheme build configuration to release, then click Run to build app, after that:

1. I open instruments and select automation tracetemplate , select target app
2. Then add an new script
3. Click Record button
4. After app started from simulator, the instruments show an error message: Target app not frontmost;

But when I changed run's scheme build configuration to debug, it works fine.

Note: Code Signing using iOS Developer both debug and release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XCode (not in Instruments) select Product > Profile, and after if compiles, choose automation. Wait for the app to start, then stop the track: you should be able to run it from the editor. If not, delete the Instruments and iPhone Simulator folders from the Library and restart Instruments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have resolved this issue with your steps.